# ExtJs 4 callbacks

Tags: javascript, extjs, extjs4, extjs4.1, extjs4.2

I had a hard time trying to find out why my assignments where lost, and found that callbacks scope was different than I thought.

What I did was to create a variable in a controller, then trying to pass a callback to a window created by the controller, then, on an event on that window, call-back a function in the controller.

For example, in my controller I have:

```
callWindow: function(){
  var myWin = Ext.Create('MyApp.view.myWin', {doSomething: this.doSomething});
},

doSomething: function(data){
  this.myData = data;
},

useTheData: function(){
  console.log(this.myData);
}
```

In myWin's controller, I have an even handler that calls doSomething this way:

```
onBtnClick: function(button){
  var win = button.up('window');
  var data = {id: 1, name: "John"}; // please, don't pay attention to this, it's a record I'm passing to the caller.
  win.doSomething(data);
}
```

As you can see, in "doSomething" function, I'm assigning the controller var myData, with the value passed by the window's controller. Initially I thought the scope of "doSomething" was the caller controller, but it's the window's controller, that's why useTheData gives an error saying this.myData is null.

I've solved the problem by passing a new parameter named "caller: this", and in doSomething, receiving that parameter, and using it instead of "this".

The question is, is there a easy (with less steps) way to do this?.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You need to apply a scope for your callback to the window and use [Ext.callback](http://docs.sencha.com/ext-js/4-1/#!/api/Ext-method-callback)

```
callWindow: function(){
  var myWin = Ext.Create('MyApp.view.myWin', {doSomething: this.doSomething, scope: this});
},

onBtnClick: function(button){
  var win = button.up('window');
  var data = {id: 1, name: "John"}; // please, don't pay attention to this, it's a record I'm passing to the caller.
  Ext.callback(win.doSomething, win.scope, [data]);
}
```

This is one way, your solution is another and there are even more.

Comment: @leonardorame Yes you are. Your function is executed in the scope of the window and you applying the controller instance as reference. My function is executed in the controller scope so you can use ´this´ for example. The `[data]` is the argument array

Comment: I removed my last comment, because I didn't see the Ext.callback call. I'll mark yours as a correct answer. Thank you.

Comment: @leonardorame You don't have that much ways if need a callback with a scope. Another variant is `Ext.isFunction(myFunc) && myFunc.apply(this, [arg1, arg2]);` but that is nearly the same then `Ext.callback`

Comment: @leonardorame I see. So take the last as another way without using the Ext.callback wrapper